Webpack node module getting added in multiple chunks in my react application
In my react application, I am using react-transition-group node module. In the prod build, webpack (5.36.2) is clubbing this module in multiple chunks and not with the vendor even though I have defined vendor splitChunks cacheGroup config as node_modules folder.
splitChunks: {
  name: false,
  cacheGroups: {
    commons:  {
      test: {
        vendor: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
      },
      name: 'vendor',
      chunks: 'initial'
    },
    default: {
      minChunks: 2,
      reuseExistingChunk: true,
      minSize: 100000
    }
  }
}

When I specify chunks as 'all', it adds all node modules in vendor making it really heavy so I would stay with 'initial'. My question is why isn't webpack making a single chunk for this reusable npm module so it can be loaded in all pages making use of it?
Also sometimes it clubs this module with components that are not needed in a particular page but get loaded through the chunk because of the node module.
for instance I have Page1 and Page2. Page1 uses ComponentA, ComponentB & ComponentC. Page2 uses ComponentX, ComponentY & ComponentZ. Webpack is clubbing react-transition-group with ComponentX in 1 chunk say 1234.dfff9099.js & with ComponentZ in another chunk say 5678.offf9099.js. Now in Page1 is loading either 1/both of these chunks causing unnecessary code to load.
I tried specifying defaultVendors: false, and by doing so it started clubbing the npm module more logically with code thats relevant for a page. However its still being added in multiple chunks, 1 per page.
Now webpack is clubbing react-transition-group with ComponentA in 1 chunk say 9999.dfuf9099.js & with ComponentZ in another chunk say 7777.ojff9099.js.
Dont understand the behaviour yet.
Is this the right chunking behaviour or there is some config that can be specified to make single chunks of node modules left out of vendor?

You want a chunk exclusively for transition group? Then use test appropriately.

@morganney thats not exactly what I want, I just want the chunking to be logical so it doesnot club modules with code thas specific to a page but gets loaded in all pages due to the node module.

Ok, well you should probably provide a reproducible example or at least more details.

@morganney adding defaultVendors: false made the chunking more logical, so react-transition-group is being added in a chunk with code thats relevant for the page. However its still being added in multiple chunks, 1 per page. Dont understand the behaviour yet.

There are two things. 1. All the issues haven't come from Webpack, sometimes the library hasn't got the ability to code splitting. 2. The best way is like the first comment. Make chunk groups based on heavy libraries. And some issues like the above one will be gone.

An a question, How did you understand The chunk of ComponentX or Page 1 contain react-transition-group?

@AmerllicA Through webpack-bundle-analyzer.
